# MinimalCD Network autoconfiguration fails

Tags: networking, ubuntu-minimal, modprobe

I'm attempting to get an Ubuntu *MinimalCD* Install working without much luck..

Working from the guide posted [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD) I can get the CD to boot and I select the `Command-Line Installer` option. After selecting my Language and Keyboard settings the installer fails on `Configure the network with DHCP` with the message:

```
                     Network autoconfiguration failed.
Your network is probably not using the DHCP protocol. Alternatively, the DHCP server may
be slow or some network hardware is not working properly.
                               <continue>
```

I can verify that my network is using DHCP and that the network hardware on the device is functional. The device in question is the [EBM-LX800](http://jp.avalue.com.tw/products/EBM-LX800.cfm) (AMD Geode LX800 5.25” Mini Module with AMD Geode LX800 + CS5536 Chipset) which uses the `10/100Base-Tx Fast Ethernet compatible: Realtek RTL 8101L` Ethernet interface.

From here If I enter *tty* and `modprobe --list | grep net` I see a very large list of drivers, *some of which look like they may be the correct driver for my device* however i'm not sure which to choose or how to ensure the driver is available for the network configuration.

#### Note:

*I have not listed the drivers from the modprobe --list command because there are way too many to copy them all by hand.*

Comment: This happens to me all the time.  Try backing out of the install step and re-entering.  It has fixed it for me before.

Comment: @aking1012 I've attempted the install ~20-30 times now. running `modprobe` before and after the networking step, and re-running said step after the modprobe command has been run.

Comment: Does the ubuntu live media boot? with networking?

Comment: the Live cd boots me to `BusyBox`, attempting to exit `busybox` results in `Target filesystem doesn't have requested /sbin/init` however the .img md5 checks out so does the 'disc check' on the live CD...

Comment: If the liveCD can't get passed busybox I have no idea.  Sounds like some unsupported hardware.

Comment: liveCD not booting is a separate issue and should be dealt with in [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/109239/cannot-boot-livecd-on-amd-geode-lx800) question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try disabling `Ultra DMA`<sub>[UMDA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UDMA)</sub> from the BIOS menu.
On the **[EBM LX800](http://jp.avalue.com.tw/products/EBM-LX800.cfm)** you can find this under the *internal peripherals* sub-menu.

Disabling this option allowed me to install the minimalCD 11.10 i386 desktop edition.