# Cannot boot liveCD on AMD Geode LX800

Tags: live-cd, boot-failure

When trying to boot from the liveCD (Ubuntu 11.10 i386 Desktop) After a *long* wait I get stopped at **BusyBox**. 
Running `exit` from **BusyBox** exits, then errors, then reloads **BusyBox**.
This is the error:

```
Target filesystem doesn't have requested /sbin/init
```

[Here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1CQboj6mmGM) is a *long* youtube video of my install in process.. the first two menus are taken over by glare but they are showing that I am using the default 'mode' and 'options' for the install.

I have run a `memtest` (one pass, took an hour) and it came back good. I have also done a md5 check on my disc image, which was also good. I have *checked the disc* from the boot menu and it came back good.

I can admit that my search on the supported hardware came back a bust but I also could not find a few things I knew were supported so i'm assuming my use of the tool was poor at best.
Upon a quick search of google I found that people did have luck getting ubuntu to load (albeit older versions) on this board. Can I get any suggestions on how I can overcome this problem?  Should I try an older version? and if so is there really a point in going pre 10.04?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try disabling `Ultra DMA`<sub>[UMDA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UDMA)</sub> from the BIOS menu.
On the **[EBM LX800](http://jp.avalue.com.tw/products/EBM-LX800.cfm)** you can find this under the *internal peripherals* sub-menu.

Disabling this option allowed me to boot from the liveCD into Unity with full device support. I'm unsure how this will translate to speeds afterwards, however it does allow you to boot.